# How to use value from input tag in the same form

Tags: html, php-7

I am looking how to reuse the value="typed_from_user" into another  tag in the same formulary without using js, just PHP & HTML.

Is it even possible?

For example, here i want to reuse the word 'pizza'

```
<form>
    <input name="hello" type="text" value="I want pizza">
    <input name="order" type="text" value="pizza">
</form>
```

maybe something storing it in a variable?

```
<form>
    <input name="hello" type="text" value="<?php echo $whatyouwant ;?>">
    <input name="lunch" type="text" value="<?php echo substr($whatyouwant,7,5);?>"><!--cut it from letter 7, the word pizza-->
    <input name="order" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

yeah, supouse that we know where exactly starts the word pizza

This are the files i am using as tests

- action.php
- form.php

---

```
<?php
//action.php

$var = $_POST['hello'];
$var_lunch= $_POST['lunch'];
echo "hello: $var<br>";
echo "lunch: $var_lunch<br>";
?>
```

file form.php:

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>test-page</title>
    <!--bootstrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../css/bootstrap/bootstrap_v4.0.0.css">
</header>
<body>
<?php
$whatyouwant=777;
?>
<form method="post" action="action.php">        
        <input name="hello" type="text" value="<?php echo $whatyouwant ;?>">
        <input name="lunch" type="text" value="<?php echo substr($whatyouwant,7,5);?>">
        <input name="order" type="submit" value="submit">
</form>        
</body>
</html>
```

OUTPUT:
hello: i want pizza
lunch:

Comment: Yes, that is how to reuse text using only HTML and PHP. Did it not work when you tried it?

Comment: It is not working when the value is changed. Supouse, there is a <input name="hello" type="text" value="<?php $whatyouwant=777; echo $whatyouwant ;?>">, then the second input prints 777 no matter if you write I WANT PIZZA

Comment: For that you need to submit the form

Comment: i tried submiting the form, and it need to refresh the input value before it sends. so is not an option, but thanks

Comment: You need to not call action.php but instead form.php and have `if (isset($_POST["order"]) { $whatyouwant = $_POST['lunch'];
} else $whatyouwant = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to get the input value form one text field to another text field only using PhP and HTML, I have to say that it is quite impossible.  PhP is the server side language so to get the value from one field to another, it must first reach the server and then it display but will show error in PhP.

To achieve this, you have to use JS. You can achieve this from just a few lines of code using jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I will look for some jQuery possible solutions

Comment: If it gave you idea or help you solve the problem, please accept the answer

Comment: Yeah, i am sorry, y thought i've clicked already. Thanks again from Madrid!